# How to filter the String based on , and delete the duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Let's Assume I have DataTable in Ms sql  that represents simple matrix

Existing Table

```
    ids_cloumn
    ========================
    RX ,BX , AS , RX ,BX , AS
    XR ,Xs , AS     
    XR ,Xs , AS,XR ,Xs , AS
    RX ,BX , AS , 
    RX ,BX , AS ,
```

I want to filter the duplicated data in string and data is separated by ' , '

```
  ids_column
    ========================
    RX ,BX , AS 
    XR ,Xs , AS     
    XR ,Xs , AS
    RX ,BX , AS , 
    RX ,BX , AS ,
```

right  now i am using  this But this approach is unsuccessful

```
declare @i int
declare @c char
declare @rst varchar(8000)
set @i=1
set @rst=substring(‘aaassrt’,1,1)
set @c=”

while @i<=len(‘aaassrt’)
begin
set @c=substring(‘aaassrt’,@i,1)
if charindex( @c,@rst,1)=0
set @rst=@rst+@c
set @i=@i+1
end
select @rst
```

Comment: Comma separated string in column +1. This solution provides extraordinary performance, it is easy to extend and  parse :)

Comment: The proper way to represent a matrix in SQL is using a table with (essentially) three columns for row, column, and value.  Using delimited lists is simply a very bad data structure that is hard to use.

Comment: @lad2025 can you expalin a bit more

Comment: @Ranju This is irony. The reality is that data is column should be **atomic**

Comment: @GordonLinoff Can you please explain a bit more

Comment: You refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows may be resolved staff

Comment: @Ranju The way you have data in a column (1,2,24,...) is delimited strings because data is in the form of a string delimited(separated) by a comma. Gordon is saying (correctly) that it is a very bad data structure and is hard to use. He is also explaining how to represent a matrix in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i hope this will help you [xQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191476.aspx) but i am not able to remove last comma of string :( another thing for my below query you have to keep specific space between character

```
declare @temp table (Id int,val nvarchar(33))
insert into @temp values (1,'RX ,BX ,AS ,RX ,BX ,AS')
insert into @temp values (2,'XR ,Xs ,AS     ')
insert into @temp values (3,'XR ,Xs ,AS ,XR ,Xs ,AS')
insert into @temp values (4,'RX ,BX ,AS ,')
insert into @temp values (5,'RX ,BX ,AS ,')

select Id,
REPLACE(cast(cast('<d>'+ replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(val)), ' ,','</d><d>')+'</d>'  as xml)
.query('distinct-values(/d)') as varchar), ' ', ' ,')AS [val]
from @temp;
```

RESULT

[image]

Comment: I am happy for the solution but please help me the above dataTable  its not working that :( i am not able apply for the Table in SQL

Comment: may be you can help me on this you know how to solve this    Msg 6354, Level 16, State 10, Line 2
Target string size is too small to represent the XML instance

Comment: instead of `varchar` define `nvarchar(max)`

Comment: Can you explain this what happening here  REPLACE(cast(cast('<d>'+ replace(LTRIM(RTRIM(val)), ' ,','</d><d>')+'</d>'  as xml)
.query('distinct-values(/d)') as varchar), ' ', ' ,')AS [val]

Comment: @Ranju convert string into XML then apply query on XML then replace comma on result

Answer (score 0):

This is one way on doing it:

```
declare @data table(ids nvarchar(100))
insert into @data(ids) values
('1 , 2 , 4 , 23 , 1 , 2 , 4 , 23 ,')
, ('1 , 3 , 4 , 3 , 4 ')
, ('2 , 3 , 6 ,')
, ('3 , 5 , 8 , 3 , 5  ')
, ('1 , 7 , 9 ')

Select distinct xml.ids, LTRIM(RTRIM(x.id.value('.', 'varchar(5)'))) as id
From (
    Select ids
        , CAST('<x>'+REPLACE(ids, ',', '</x><x>') + '</x>' as xml) as data
    From @data
) as xml
Cross Apply data.nodes('x') as x(id)
Where LTRIM(RTRIM(x.id.value('.', 'varchar(5)'))) <> ''
```

Like it has been said by everyone else, you should not store comma separated value in one single column.
You should record it in rows in another table and join it to your main table.